# Change Outlook's data location

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2010

I'm installing `MagicCard` on my grandmother's computer which restores the main partition each time the computer is rebooted. However, I would like to keep the data from Outlook (contacts, emails, etc.), so I want it to be kept in a different partition. How do I tell Outlook where to store its data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the control panel, make sure you have a view that shows all the icons, and look for the `Mail` control panel item.  Open this and you should see a dialog box with three buttons.  The middle button says "`Data Files...`", and will open a window that lets you set this.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a .pst file, which you probably are if you don't connect to an exchange server, just do a search for *.pst, including hidden folders.

Sorry, should have read the question better. I always just copy it to the place I want it, usually a mail folder in My Douments, and then click File, ope, Outlook Data File..., and navigate to it. Since the main partition gets restored you can use any spot on another drive. '